# Wordpress - Nested shortcodes rendering

Tags: wordpress, nested

first of all I know which my problem is not at all related to the **sage** project but I know that your advanced wordpress knowledge can help me to get through that.

p.s. I've been creating my shortcodes upon sage scaffolding.

I built two shortcodes for nested using:

```
[outdoor]
    [outdoor_item title="My title 1" color="orange"]<strong>The</strong> 1st Content[/outdoor]
    [outdoor_item title="My title 2" color="blue"]<strong>The</strong> 2nd Content[/outdoor]
    [outdoor_item title="My title 3" color="green"]<strong>The</strong> 3rd Content[/outdoor]
    [outdoor_item title="My title 4" color="red"]<strong>The</strong> 4th Content[/outdoor]
[/outdoor]
```

After lots of hours searching something in stackoverflow and google I figured it out that I had to apply `do_shortcode()` in my RAW `outdoor` shortcontent content... something like this:

```
add_shortcode('outdoor', function($atts, $content, $tag) {
    return '<div class="outdoor">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
});
```

and then my problem comes out... **the function `do_shortcode()` renders ONLY my first `outdoor_item` and ignores every `outdoor_item` else.** It outputs something like this:

```
<div class="outdoor">
    <div class="outdoor-item" style="background-color: orange">
        <h1>My title 1</h1>
        <div class="outdoor-item-content">
            <strong>The</strong> 1st Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

p.s. I've tried `do_shortcode()`, `apply_filters('the_content', $content)` and even call `wp_reset_postdata()` after each `outdoor_item`. What else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had similar issue.
I needed to wrap elements into the bootstrap table so the shortcode should be the following:

```
[table]
  [fb_review href="" name="" date=""][/fb_review]
  [fb_review href="" name="" date=""][/fb_review]
  [fb_review href="" name="" date=""][/fb_review]
  [fb_review href="" name="" date=""][/fb_review]
  [fb_review href="" name="" date=""][/fb_review]
[/table]
```

and this should produce the following html:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"><div class="fb-review">Some content</div></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><div class="fb-review">Some content</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"><div class="fb-review">Some content</div></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><div class="fb-review">Some content</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"><div class="fb-review">Some content</div></div>
</div>
```

I looked for different ways how to handle this but then decided to parse the `$content` string by myself

here is the part of `functions.php`:

```php
//this function just wraps the compiled nested shortcode elements
function responsive_table($attrs, $items = []) {
  if (count($items) > 0) {
    $result = '';
    $counter = 0;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
      if (!($counter % 2)) {
        $result .= '<div class="row">';
      }
      $result .= '<div class="col-md-6">' . $item . '</div>';
      if ($counter % 2) {
        $result .= '</div>';
      }
      $counter++;
    }
    if ($counter % 2) {
      $result .= '</div>';
    }
    return $result;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

// this function parses the content, fetches internal shortcodes, compiles them and passes to responsive_table
function responsive_table_for($attrs, $content=null) {
  if ($content != null && $content != '') {
    $content_matches = [];
    preg_match_all('/\[.+?\[.+?\]/', $content, $content_matches); // TODO: this doesn't support nested shortcodes
    $content_array = [];
    foreach ($content_matches[0] as $item) {
      $content_array[] = do_shortcode($item);
    }
    return responsive_table($attrs, $content_array);
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

add_shortcode('table', 'responsive_table_for');
```

Maybe this way is not the best but it works for me.